# SQL Server - PIVOT on CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

I have a table like this:

```
Store   Holiday    Date_Index     Temp
 123      XMAS         t_0         34.9
 234      XMAS         t_1          M
 123      XMAS         t_1         22.3
 123      XMAS         t_2         28.5
```

I'm trying to pivot it to something like this:

```
Store   Holiday    t_0     t_1      t_2
 123     XMAS      34.9    22.3     28.5
 234     XMAS      32.1    NULL     29.5
```

By using:

```
Select *
from
(
select Store, Holiday, Date_Index, Temp
from myTable
)
PIVOT
(
sum(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Temp) = 1 THEN cast(Temp as decimal) ELSE NULL END)
FOR DATE_INDEX IN ([t_0],[t_1],[t_2])
) as PivotTable;
```

My issue is that the Temp column contains a mix of letters and numbers.  I've tried to pivot on a sum of a case statement but am getting an error message.  How would I correctly compensate for non-numeric characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. However, you can do it in the anchor query like this:

```
Select *
from
(
  select Store, Holiday, Date_Index, 
    CASE WHEN ISNumeric(Temp) = 1 THEN CAST(Temp AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) ELSE 0 END AS Temp
  from myTable
) as t
PIVOT
(
  sum(Temp)
  FOR DATE_INDEX IN ([t_0],[t_1],[t_2])
) as P;
```

I used the [`ISNUMERIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) built in function to replace those non numeric values with 0 and cast the whole column to be `decimal` before the pivot. Then in the `pivot` just use `SUM(temp)`.

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c059f/5)

Results:

```
| Store | Holiday |    t_0 |  t_1 |    t_2 |
|-------|---------|--------|------|--------|
|   123 |    XMAS |   34.9 | 22.3 |   28.5 |
|   234 |    XMAS | (null) |    0 | (null) |
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way for the same and probably the easier one -

```
SELECT Store
      ,Holiday
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Date_Index = 't_0' THEN Temp END) AS t_0
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Date_Index = 't_1' THEN Temp END) AS t_1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Date_Index = 't_2' THEN Temp END) AS t_2
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Store
        ,Holiday
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is:  Instead of selecting/pivoting directly from the table, select from a CTE which replaces all non-numeric `Temp` values with `NULL`.