# SQL Server Pivot on string data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a table like this:

[image]

And I want to change table structure to this format:

[image]

I used this query :

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([Q]) Frommytable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = 'Select [user],' + @SQL + '
From mytablle
 Pivot ( sum(Answer) For [Q] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'

Exec(@SQL);
```

But it didn't work as we can't use sum function for [Answer] (it's string).
What is your guide for this problem?

Comment: Well if it's a string then what aggregation do you want? Perhaps `MAX`? Which version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Yes. Using a `MIN` or `MAX` function should do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - PIVOT on CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346343/sql-server-pivot-on-case-statement)

Comment: My data is string! Min or Max doesn't work for it. I want just data. my question is similar  SQL Server - PIVOT on CASE statement but my data is not number so we cannot use numerical function

Comment: So cast it. If you supplied actual sample data in your question it might encourage someone to answer.

Comment: `MIN`/`MAX` work fine for strings. They aren't "numerical functions"

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pivot and lead function to get your result.

Check here for reference:

[Microsoft Docs - Lead function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Microsoft Docs - Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Here you have two examples:

```
select 
    [user],
    max([x]) [x],
    max([y]) [y],
    max([z]) [z]
from tbl
pivot (max(answer) for q in ([x],[y],[z])) p
group by [user]

-- Result
/*
+------+---+---+---+
| user | x | y | z |
+------+---+---+---+
| i1   | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| i2   | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| i3   | 1 | 4 | 6 |
+------+---+---+---+
*/
```

```
with t as (
    select 
    [user],
    [x],
    Lead([y],1) over(partition by [user] order by [id]) [y],
    Lead([z],2) over(partition by [user] order by [id]) [z]
    from tbl
    pivot (max(answer) for q in ([x],[y],[z])) p
)
select * from t
where [x] is not null

-- Result
/*
+------+---+---+---+
| user | x | y | z |
+------+---+---+---+
| i1   | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| i2   | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| i3   | 1 | 4 | 6 |
+------+---+---+---+
*/
```

Note: this query uses the id to order rows in the lead function.

Comment: thank you very much. the first code worked without any errors but display all cells "Null". I don't what is the problem