# SQL How to add a conditional to the aggregate function within a pivot table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, conditional-statements, pivot, case

I tried to create a pivot table for all the relevant timestamps in this database, but discovered that the MAX() function in the aggregate statement of the pivot table was returning values that I didn't necessarily want. I'm trying to track timestamps to look at bottlenecks and average times between events.

For this database there is a record for every event and each event is timestamped. Certain events can be "cleared", but these are recorded as events with their own timestamps as well (they get marked as a "cleared" = 1 event). Let's say an order is completed, and then cleared--when I pull the MAX(EventTimeStamp) for that order, I will get the cleared timestamp which can be misleading when I try to look at the data. I instead want to get a NULL value returned.

Here is what the original data looks like:

| Case | State | EventTimeStamp | Cleared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OrderReceived | 2024-03-20 12:20 | 0 |
| 1 | Completed | 2024-03-20 12:51 | 0 |
| 1 | Completed | 2024-03-20 12:55 | 1 |
| 2 | OrderReceived | 2024-03-21 10:00 | 0 |
| 2 | Completed | 2024-03-22 08:00 | 0 |

There are maybe 25 different states that I'd like to track for many different cases which is why I pivoted it to look like this

| Case | OrderReceived | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-20 12:20 | 2024-03-20 12:55 |
| 2 | 2024-03-21 10:00 | 2024-03-22 08:00 |

For these cases I'd like to have a table that looks like this. Since the last Completed Event was a "Cleared" event I'd like it to read as NULL:

| Case | OrderReceived | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-20 12:20 | NULL |
| 2 | 2024-03-21 10:00 | 2024-03-22 08:00 |

Here is the condensed query for the pivot table:

```
SELECT [CaseID]
    ,[OrderReceived]
    ,[Completed]

FROM (SELECT [CaseID]
        ,[Cleared]
        ,[State]
        ,[EventTimeStamp]   
    FROM CaseTracking
        ) AS SourceTable

PIVOT (
    MAX(EventTimeStamp)
    FOR [State] IN ([OrderReceived]
    ,[Completed])) AS PivotTable
```

I'm not sure how to go about this to be honest. I thought about using a CASE statement to pair with the MAX() function, but I don't know how to evaluate the Cleared variable that is paired with the MAX(EventTimeStamp).

I do know that in layman's terms my conditional statement is something like:
IF the "Cleared" value for the MAX(EventTimeStamp) = 0 THEN return MAX(EventTimeStamp).
IF the "Cleared" value for the MAX(EventTimeStamp) = 1 THEN return NULL.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: Generally, don't use `PIVOT`. You are *far* better off using conditional aggregation. `PIVOT` is quite restrictive in its syntax. You can't mix aggregates (easily) or easily vary the conditions you want to pivot on with `PIVOT`, where as it's very simple with aggregates and `CASE` expressions.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346343/sql-server-pivot-on-case-statement

Comment: I'm happy to try achieving this without pivoting, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Would this be with "group by"? I defaulted to pivot since that's what I'm more accustomed to on excel

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your example to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/U6HXW-Xe

Answer (score 0):

I used the recommendations from [SQL Server - PIVOT on CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346343/sql-server-pivot-on-case-statement) and used '1990-1-1' as a temp stand in for NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE CaseTracking 
(
    [Case]  VARCHAR(512),
    [State] VARCHAR(512),
    EventTimeStamp  VARCHAR(512),
    Cleared VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO CaseTracking ([Case], [State], EventTimeStamp, Cleared) VALUES
    ('1', 'OrderReceived', '2024-03-20 12:20', '0'),
    ('1', 'Completed', '2024-03-20 12:51', '0'),
    ('1', 'Completed', '2024-03-20 12:55', '1'),
    ('2', 'OrderReceived', '2024-03-21 10:00', '0'),
    ('2', 'Completed', '2024-03-22 08:00', '0');

SELECT * FROM CaseTracking


SELECT [CASE]    
      ,MAX([OrderReceived]) as [OrderReceived] 
      ,CASE MIN([Completed]) WHEN '1990-1-1' THEN NULL ELSE MIN([Completed]) END as [Completed]
FROM
(
  
SELECT [Case]
    ,[OrderReceived]
    ,[Completed]

FROM (SELECT [Case]
        ,[Cleared]
        ,[State]
        ,[EventTimeStamp]  
        ,CASE [CLEARED]  WHEN 1 THEN '1990-1-1' ELSE [EventTimeStamp] END as ets
     
    FROM CaseTracking
        ) AS SourceTable

PIVOT (
    MAX(ets)
    FOR [State] IN ([OrderReceived]
    ,[Completed])) AS PivotTable

) t
GROUP BY [CASE]
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zbtLRz-q)

| CASE | OrderReceived | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-20 12:20 | null |
| 2 | 2024-03-21 10:00 | 2024-03-22 08:00 |

Comment: Breakdown of steps https://dbfiddle.uk/4jt_5ZEB

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me how to introduce a conditional in a way to get around the pivot. I'm going to continue to fiddle with this since it seems like I run into problems when there is a Cleared = 0 event after a Cleared = 1 event

Ran into problems with this type of dataset:
 ('1', 'OrderReceived', '2024-03-20 12:20', '0'),
 ('1', 'Completed', '2024-03-20 12:51', '0'),
 ('1', 'Completed', '2024-03-20 12:55', '1'),
        ('1', 'Completed', '2024-03-20 12:58', '0')